# How can we get the hidden properties from an object?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I have an object, which is an instance of one of my models.
I want to get the store it belongs to, from that instance.
When digging for a way to get this store, I found this :

```
_data: Object
data: Object
dirty: true
editing: false
id: "ext-record-462"
internalId: "ext-record-462"
modified: Object
phantom: true
raw: Object
stores: Array[1]
__proto__: Object
length: 1
```

This is the console.log() of the object, and I can see a `stores` variable, which contains the array of stores that this object is linked to :

```
stores: Array[1]
    0: Class
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array[0]
```

I tried `myObject.get('stores')` and `myObject.stores` , but both returned `undefined`.
Is there a way to retrieve this information, or is it forbidden by the framework ?

Similarly, once I get the store, I would like to get the object it is linked to from a `hasMany` association.
In the console.log() of that store, i see this :

```
boundTo: Class
```

This field contains the reference to the object that has the association. But I can't get it. I tried `myStore.get('boundTo')` and `myStore.boundTo` too, but without success.

So my question is : Is there a way to get these hidden properties ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm dumb, I forgot that these objects are before all javascript objects.
But in case anybody stumbles on this, I'll leave the answer here :

You can access any property of a javascript (and therefore, any models or sencha touch object) thanks to this syntax : `myObject['myProperty']`

All you have to do is take a look at your object thanks to a dev tool in your browser, and note down the property you want to get.